# DIR-836L router suddenly stopped broadcasting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

This week I found that any of the devices I have connected to my wireless network registered my WIFI router. Then I went to check the router and was surprised to see that it seemed to be working well, with all lights green as it should be. I decided to turn it off and after a few seconds turn it on back again. It worked perfectly!
Today it happened again, so a performed the turn-off-on procedure. This time it didn't work. I went through the configuration and everything seems to be the same way it has always been. I tried reconfiguring the wireless settings, changed ports, made it invisible and back to visible, and even a hard reset and nothing.
What is curious is the fact that when I connect using a cable from the router to my PC, It works perfectly. As I said, lights are green. Help me out please, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What model/make of the router is it?

Did you perform the [30-30-30 factory reset](https://www.router-reset.com/en/30-30-30-reset-factory-defaults-wireless-router/) or just a "regular" reset?

If you have recently flashed some new firmware it might be good to do a factory reset to flush out old configs that might mess up things..

Comment: Thanks for answering! My router is a DLINK DIR-836L like 5 years old. I performed the regular reset, I guess, The one pressing down and holding with a pin a button that is almost hidden on the bottom of the device. I haven't performed any firmware update yet. Now, it started working the same way it stopped when I posted the question. It stops broadcasting from time to time now. I just turn it off and back on again and that fixes the problem. The real question now is: is it gonna die soon? is there anything I can do to prevent that? Thanks again!

Comment: If the router is acting weird and reset doesn't help, there's really no way of telling what will happen.. just hope for the best and have some old backup router ready for when(if) it dies, while waiting for some new router to arrive =)